# How to measure time elapsed of another app? (in low memory situations)

Tags: android

I am making an application that launches games (apps not made by me), and I have to measure the time elapsed of each game session for business requirement.

However, my app is killed if a large game launch and low memory occurs.

I have tried to start a long-running service, which runs a handler monitoring the package name of the foreground activity, and keep the service running at least as long as the game I launched by returning `START_STICKY`, using `startForeground()`, running on a separate process, but with no luck.

I tried to send broadcast in `onDestory()`, but it is not called.

I have the platform signature and can have my app run as system app by adding `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"`, but does it help?

Or is there better approach to do the measurement? Thanks!